# TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

well, I am getting this error in the console when I submit the form.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null
```

I have a form where I need to upload text, files so the file field is optional? which means it can be null if the user does not want to upload a file, here is the code where the error happend.

the column name is this `image1_url`

```
    writeFileToCloudinary(files.file).then((secureUrl) => {
    Posts.update(
      { image1_url: secureUrl },
      {
        where: { id: postId },
      }
    );
  });
```

any idea?
thanks

Comment: Use optional chaining because if the variable 'files' does not exist it will not look further to see if it has a 'file' key - writeFileToCloudinary(files?.file)

Comment: well, it works but i got another error in the writeFileToCloudinary function, 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mimetype' of undefined

this is the code
  const prefix = `data:${file.mimetype};base64,`;

Comment: It's hard for me to tell what is wrong here as it seems it is something in the code of the cloudinary function as it expects an object and modifies it internally in some way, and in this case you are passing 'null'. You should be able to handle it with a catch statement, however you can also wrap this piece of code in an 'if ' statement - if (files?.file) { *your code here*}. That way you wont run the function unless you have a file present

Comment: well, let me share more code so you can understand better, please check the update

Comment: With the provided code it doesn't throw an error for me. Instead the prefix is 'data:undefined;base64' which is right when the file is 'null'. By removing the optional chaining in prefix I get the error you mentioned.

Comment: well, I figured it out thanks:)